# Does explicit client evaluation of where clause require AsEnumerable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

StandardizeUrl is function written in c#. Suppose it is used in the select query then the function is applied in memory after the data is returned by sql - example:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .OrderByDescending(blog => blog.Rating)
    .Select(
        blog => new { Id = blog.BlogId, Url = StandardizeUrl(blog.Url) })
    .ToList();
```

This question is about using a custom c# function in WHERE clause. The below return runtime exception:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Where(blog => StandardizeUrl(blog.Url).Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToList();
```

Solution is given here: Link- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#explicit-client-evaluation

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(blog => StandardizeUrl(blog.Url).Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToList();
```

Why does the link says we can either use AsEnumerable **or** ToList. For example if I don't use AsEnumerable then it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you get "client evaluation" with methods like `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` **before** using the `Where()` call. That way the data is (fully) transferred to the client (your C# application) and then filtered on the client side, where you have access to your `StandardizeUrl()` method. The documentation does not talk about the `ToList()` after the `Where()` call.

Comment: If I remove AsEnumerable then it doesn't work. You means the WHERE they are referring to is the one after .ToList?

Comment: @variable There is only one `Where()` call in the example and they say that you have to use methods like `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` **before** the `Where()` call to have "client evaluation". If you remove your `AsEnumerable()` call, then you don't have such a method before the `Where()` call and it will fail.